# Conditional Probabilities and non-zero condtions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

When working with conditionals $\mathcal{P}(A \mid B)$ do we have a proof obligation to show that $\mathcal{P}(B) \neq 0$ ?

In-particular, what about in the expression,
$\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) = \mathcal{P}(A \mid B) \cdot \mathcal{P}(B)$.
Is this statement valid as is, or must a non-zero proviso be made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Kolmogorov definition explicitly assumes $\mathbb{P}[B]>0$.

See [Wiki link to definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition)

**EDIT**
Typically, one uses
$$
(1) \qquad \mathbb{P}[A \cap B] = \mathbb{P}[A|B] \cdot \mathbb{P}[B]
$$
as a *definition* of $\mathbb{P}[A|B]$, meaning that we define
$$
(2) \qquad \mathbb{P}[A|B] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}.
$$
There is obviously no problem with (1) as is, except that $\mathbb{P}[A|B]$ must then be defined in some alternate way, although I am not sure what would that be. Alternatively, if we choose to go the standard way and define $\mathbb{P}[A|B]$ via (2), then the very definition requires $\mathbb{P}[B]>0$.

Comment: Thankyou! Could you please also respond to the edited version? Thanks!

Comment: @Moses please see the edit...